# QT not load file data although the file contain data

Tags: qt, file

I try to load CSV file into 'QString' (in order to convert him to html file in future)

But although the file exist and contain data QT "think" the file is an empty.

It's my function:

```
void readCSVfile(QString csvFileName, bool relativePath)
{
    QString csvFile = csvFileName;
    QString workingDir = QDir::currentPath() + "//";

    QString fullCSVpath = (relativePath ? workingDir : "") + csvFile;
    QFile csvfile(fullCSVpath);

    // verify csv file is exist
    if (!csvfile.exists())
    {
        csvfile.close();
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&csvfile);
    // test - to verify QT success to read the file.
    QString alltextTemp = in.readAll();
}
```

and it's my file content:

```
Time,Reporter,Type,Content,Screenshot,RTF Note
11/12/2013 5:37:25 PM,Asf,(Rapid Reporter version),"1.12.12.28",,
11/12/2013 5:37:25 PM,Asf,Session Reporter,"Asf",,
11/12/2013 5:37:25 PM,Asf,Session Charter,"target",,
11/12/2013 5:37:47 PM,Asf,Session End. Duration,"00:00:22",,
```

The problem: 'alltextTemp' variable contain an empty string (and not contain the file content)

The question: why? (or what I need to do to get the content)

The file haven't special permissions, etc.

QT 5.1.1

OS: Win 7 x64

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Use a _qDebug_ statement to print the _fullCSVpath_ and see if it's the file path you want, and a little glitch that i see, but i'm not sure that it can cause the problem you have: "//" - slash doesn't need to be escaped, one slash is enough (it's only the backslash character that needs to be escaped)

Comment: Remember that the default folder may not be the folder containing the executable file. With Visual Studio the default folder when debugging is the one containing the solution file.

Comment: Also I hope you are setting alltextTemp somewhere else since it will go out of scope at the next }

Comment: You need to open() the file. If the file doesn't exist, open() will fail, no need to close then. For further debugging, check all return values (open()) and check csvfile.errorString() in case of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to initialize a QFile object with the file name. This doesn't tell Qt what exactly you're trying to do with this file (are you trying to open an existing file? Create a new file? Delete an existing file?). This also doesn't allow Qt to tell you right away it could not open the file, since the constructor cannot return a value, and Qt does not use exceptions.

To actually open the file for reading you need to call the `open` member function:

```
QFile csvfile(fullCSVpath);

if ( !csvfile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
{
    Log( tr("Could not read file %1: %2") .arg( csvfile ) .arg( csvfile.errorString() );
    return false;
}

QTextStream in(&csvfile);
```

Note that it is a good programming practice to print the descriptive error messages, so the user of your application knows:

- Which file was attempted to be open
- What you tried to do with the file (read? write? create?)
- Why the file failed to open.